# Do div's Mess up Text Selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have looked everywhere on the internet and can not find this answer. Do div's Mess up Text Selection? I made a popup in html and the div's inside it will not let me select the text? Why not?

Comment: Can you post your code, please?

Comment: Sure, this is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/7wNT8/

Comment: sorry if the code was messy, if you want me to, i can clean it up?

Comment: I upvoted this because I'm not sure what's causing it either.  Seems if you click and drag from outside the div beneath the tabs it selects the text just fine.  I get the "text" vertical-bar cursor but cannot select any text.

Comment: This might help, this one works: http://jsfiddle.net/jdavis78/4nbyA/4/

Comment: It said i could not self answer...but i found it! YES!!!! Ok, the z-index had to be set to 99999 on the code: 

 

    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 1;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be experiencing an issue that is browser specific.  I did not have any issue selecting the text in Safari.

Text selection may differ from browser to browser, especially when you consider that browser plugins may override how text selection works in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

That's the point of a modal. If you want to be able to select the text behind the popup, change `modal: true;` to `modal: false;`

Comment: @SenorAmor - What are you talking about?

Comment: He's not talking about the text *behind* the popup.  He's talking about the text *inside* the popup.